# web3.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: solidity, web3js, require

I've been confused by the web3.js all day.

I created the **web.js** for setting and initialize Web3, and it appears the following message：

[image]

And I install web3 by `npm install web3`, the version of web3 is `1.5.2`
the version of node.js is `14.17.0`, the npm is `6.14.13`.

should I import the web3.min.js or I just miss something essential?

the code of **web3.js** shown below:

```
// Initialize Web3
var Web3 = require("web3"); << where the error is
var web3 = new Web3("https://localhost:8545");

// Set Account
web3.eth.defaultAccount = 'xxx';

// Set Contract Abi
var ABI = [abi];

// Set Contract Address
var contractAddress = 'xxx';

// Set the Contract
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);
```

Comment: Are you using raw html or some framework like react or angular? For raw html use web3.min.js.

Comment: which means if I just use html and js, I've better install the web3 by npm right?

Comment: Running `npm install` only applies to a project managed by npm. If your project is a pure html and js files without a build tool like webpack, or browserify then you have to use web3.min.js. If you use a build tool then check the documentation, but npm install web3 works in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I find out where the problem is.

I should introduce the js file in html by following order:

```
<script src="web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="web3.js"></script>
<script src="htmlfile.js"></script>
```

Although I've cleaned up the error, I find out that contract.methods didn't work. I think that should be another problem.